# Parameterized Update Query for Sql server in ASP.net with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to write a paramaterized update query to insert values into an Sql Server Express Database. The query I have written is:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "update tblposts set title=@ptitle, pdate=@pd, 
                   content=@pcontent where pid=@p"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ptitle", txtTitle.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pcontent", txtcontent.InnerText)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pd", DateTime.Now.ToString)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", postid)
```

On running `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`, I get number of rows affected as 1, but the change is not reflected in the database.

On printing the query using `Debug.Write`, I get the query not with the parameter values, but the names of the parameters itself (ie. @pcontent, @title etc)

What can be the mistake here?

Comment: Are you using the same database your application is? Are you running this in a transaction that gets rolled back?

Comment: i am not using a transaction. only this application is using the database

Comment: Are there any update triggers on this table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you're `AddWithValue` you need to include the **@** symbol on the front of the parameter, so:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptitle", txtTitle.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcontent", txtcontent.InnerText)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pd", DateTime.Now.ToString)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", postid)
```

I'm guessing that it's executing correctly but there where clause is blank, so perhaps updating a blank row.

Anyway, try the above and it should update as expected.

**Edit to Add**

The `CommandText` will always only have the `@value` in there, it will not substitue the parameter values into the string.

You would need to loop through the `cmd.Parameters` collection to write out the values.

Comment: adding the '@' symbol did not change the effect. I will also add, that I have tried the parameterized query for insert and select queries, and it works, but not working for update queries

Comment: Have you done a `Debug.Write` with the actual values? i.e. `Debug.Write(postid)`?

Comment: I am getting expected values for postid, but strangely old values for txtTitle.Text and txtContent.innerText. I guess the problem lies there

Comment: A very subtle mistake. I was reading values from database on page load event, and on click of a button, updating these values. I hadnt checked for IsPostBack condition. So the answer stands right. Thanks :)

Comment: Excellent, pleased to hear. Still, the pesky `IsPostBack` cycle is always a gotcha! Pleased it's sorted.